# Add new user in a sharepoint group with more than 5000 users

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, list-view-threshold, azure-ad

I have a SharePoint site the is used by internal and extarnal users. We use the default visitor group to manage the access. The group has more than 5k users. I cannot add new user in the group and they cannot enter as visitor.

My power automate process fails for every new user added. If I try to add the user from the SharePoint interface I have the same error message. The error detail is:

"The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold"

I understand the threshold limitation, and I think that the best solution is to migrate the users in an Azure Security Group and then add the Azure Security Group to the SharePoint group. However I would like this as a last resource, because I will have other impacts elsewhere.

---

I tried to follow the [office support](https://support.office.com/en-US/client/results?Shownav=true&lcid=1033&ns=SPOSTANDARD&version=16&omkt=en-US&helpID=LargeList&ver=16&linkid=2227651), so I added index columns and edited the list view. The error is still there.

My doubt is about the counter of the group:
[image]
I start receiving error, after 7500 users more or less. Why I did not receive these errors before? Is it possible that the group became unstable after 7500 elements?
Moreover, when my powerautomate process run the counter will increment by one (it seems added correctly), but the user cannot enter. Any help or opinion is appreciated.

Comment: I also try with powershell and I receive the same error
"The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to modify the threshold for SharePoint online. As you said, our recommendation is to use Azure Security Group.

It is unclear why the error message is only appearing after 7,500 users. It is possible that the group became unstable after this number of elements, but without more information it is difficult to determine the cause.

As for the power automate process, it seems to be adding the user correctly but the user cannot enter. This may be due to other permissions or access issues.

Comment: I use the Azure Security Group approach: I migrate the user in the ad group. I put the ad group in the spo group. The power automate flows run good. The counter in sharepoint is still at 7500 but it is an aesthetic leasure. Thanks